# How to set the width of the input type=file?

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside which lot of td's. Inside one of the td i have "input type=file". I need to decrease the size of this input type, but the problem is it is not minimizing lower than 70px (i guess the minimum is 70px). because of this it is overlapping with the other td.

```
<td class="AttachOnMouseOutText" 
    id="fileid" 
    nowrap="nowrap" 
    style="padding-right:15px; 
           padding-left: 10px;" 
    valign="top" 
    onClick="fad_open();" 
    onMouseOver="highlightBG('fileid',0,'add','add_over.gif');
                 this.style.cursor='hand';
                 return true;" 
    onMouseOut="highlightBG('fileid',1,'add','add.gif'); 
                return true;">


<p class="Margin" 
       style="position:relative;">

    <input type="file" 
               name="AttachLink"  
               style="position: absolute; 
                      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=0); 
                      opacity:0; 
                      width:70px; 
                      height:50px; 
                      cursor: hand; 
                      left:-25px;" 
               title="Add File Attachment" 
               onChange="getWeblink();">

    <img src="#ContactsImagePath#add.gif" 
         alt="Add File Attachment" 
         border="0" 
         align="middle" 
         name="add" 
         id="add" 
         onClick="fad_open();">

</p>

    <span>Add File</span>
```

[image]

Comment: @chandu Yes because that made so much sense. Thanks for that comment.

Comment: well, it is more than 1000 lines of code with some coldfusion inputs. cannot really paste that into a fiddle :(

Comment: whats the size of the add.gif image?

Comment: add.gif is of only 1KB..

Answer (score 0):

create a class and close the input. try this one

```
.myfile::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.myfile {
    position: absolute; 
 width:70px; background:(255,255,255,0); height:50px; cursor: hand; left:-25px; display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nY8L9/1/

Answer (score 0):

**First option**

You can resize the input lower than 70px, the sizing issue looks like its something to do with the image underneath or the td.

If you look on the input you will see that it has an inline style of opacity that is set to 0, so your not going to see the input no matter how much you resize it in your stylesheet.

Check the dimensions of the image underneath and resize that.

**Second option**

Add a width attribute on the td itself, for example

```
<td width="20">20px td</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard because we don't know what's your `.margin` class, nor the size of your image You can try this fix. But it might not wor if other css declarations cause conflit.

```
<p class="Margin" style="position:relative; width:YOUR_WIDTH;">
    <input style="etc.etc.etc. width:100%;etc.>
    ...
    <img style="max-width:100%;">
```

Note: not sure why your input has left:-25px. If you add a background color and set it to full opacity, you'll see the negative left position creates a weird clicking zone. Personally, I'd change it to `left:0`